# file system not mounted should display it is not mounted

Tags: filesystems

I need to check a particular file system is mounted or not . I know we can find out this from df -k.But here if a particular file system is not mounted, the error should display "cronshadow(file system-example) is not mounted ".I will give you an example output of df -k

```
Filesystem            kbytes    used   avail capacity  Mounted on
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0    4130982 1463894 2625779    36%    /
/proc                      0       0       0     0%    /proc
fd                         0       0       0     0%    /dev/fd
mnttab                     0       0       0     0%    /etc/mnttab

/dev/dsk/c2t3d0s0    2053605 1815547  176450    92%    /psa_shdw
mmr1asxx:/crnonshdw  106687632 92602932 14084700    87%    /crnonshdw
```

Here which file system i marked with asterisk is not mounted ,need to display amessage like  ---"crnonshdw is not mounted"

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy one with a simple `grep`:

```
if ! df -k | grep -q 'crnonshdw'; then
    printf 'crnonshdw is not mounted\n'
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `mount` command to find this out:

```
$ mount | grep cronshadow
```

#### Example

```
$ if ! mount | grep -q "cronshadow"; then echo "not mounted";fi
not mounted
```

You can also say it like this:

```
$  mount | grep -q "cronshadow" || echo "not mounted"
not mounted
```

Answer (score 0):

At least on my system, I have a `mountpoint` command that lets you check if a directory has something mounted on it. So you could:

```sh
if ! mountpoint -q /crnonshdw; then
    echo "cronshadow(file system-example) is not mounted"
fi
```

Alternatively, if you don't have that command, a simple approach is to make sure the mounted filesystem contains a "flag" file, which you can test for:

```sh
if ! [ -e /crnonshdw/.mounted ]; then
    echo "cronshadow(file system-example) is not mounted"
fi
```

You can of course also put the flag file inside the directory on the parent filesystem (it will be hidden when the other filesystem is mounted on top), then you'd take out the `!`.

Comment: hi i tried this but its not getting .Using rsh i need to logged into two systems and need to  check in that two systems,whether the particular filesystem is mounted or not.if it is mounted ,print "status 0k".if it is not mounted in system1, print "filesystem is not mounted on system1" and if it is not mounted in system2,print "filesystem is not mounted on system2".

Comment: @Ranjith.R which one of the two approaches did you try? And did it give any error messages?